# Is there a better way to deal with unbalanced data than the preprocessing filter SMOTE?

Tags: weka

I am currently working with WEKA and I would appreciate yor advice regarding preprocessing filters when it comes to unbalanced attribute data. I was previously recommended to use the SMOTE filter in order to deal with the problem. I was wondering if anyone could propose any alternative solution. The classifier I am mainly using is MultilayerPerceptron and the SMOTE filter seems to be working decently, but I would like to know if there is another possible method.

Answer (score 0):

Cost-sensitive classification is another approach. See FAQ [I have unbalanced data now what](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/faqs/i_have_unbalanced_data_now_what/) on the Weka wiki.